# How to change the text in the very top header in the Magento Porto theme?

Tags: porto-theme

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
```

I have spent all day yesterday trying to figure this out unsuccessfully. In the Porto Theme Demo 1 - there is a black banner on the very top which says:

Get Up to 40% OFF New-Season Styles MEN WOMEN *Limited time only  X

https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/demo1_en/

**I actually want to keep this banner but put my own text in there.** I've googled, googled, and googled and can't find anything about this even on their official documentation page. I can't submit a ticket to Porto because I bought the theme like 6 months ago and I'm just now starting to use it. I think many people are using Porto and someone surely must have dealt with this before?

---

Updated later on August 12th, 2021:

I believe @Marcony Monteiro is onto something. I can't do Development mode and I've gone through tons of CMS Static Blocks to no avail.

I did discover something interesting though:

- if I go to `Porto --> Settings Panel - General`
- there is a field called **Show Site Notice** with the following options: **No**; **Above the header**; **Below the header**; *If I set it to No - this bar disappears completely!* So it will be a matter of finding **where to edit 'Site Notice'**. Porto tries to be user-friendly so I think this must be accessible from within the Admin panel. Any ideas anyone?

---

Updated again on August 12th:

In:

```
Porto --> Settings Panel - General
```

right under the line which says:

Show Site Notice

There is a line which is labeled: **Custom Notice Block ID** and it has the following value in it:

```
porto_custom_notice
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

You can find this in:

```
Content --> Blocks
```

**The block you are looking for is this one:**

Block Title: Porto - Custom Notice Block
Identifier: porto_custom_notice

Answer (score 0):

It may be a Widget... a CMS Static Block, with layout container, is shown at the Page Top.

Or, notices. phtml in Porto theme.

If the store is still in development mode, you may enable-debug and template hints and check the section being called there.

Have you tried these?

Comment: I think you are onto something. I can't do development mode and I've gone through tons of CMS Static Blocks to no avail. I have just now discovered something interesting though - if I go to Porto --> Settings Panel - General - there is a field called "Show Site Notice" with the following options: No; Above the header; Below the header; If I set it to No - this bar disappears completely! So it will be a matter of finding where to edit 'Site Notice'. Porto tries to be user friendly so I think this must be accessible from within the Admin panel. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: In:

Porto --> Settings Panel - General
right under the line which says:

Show Site Notice

- There is a line which is labelled: Custom Notice Block ID and it has the following value in it:

porto_custom_notice
I checked the following and I am unable to find this anywhere:

Content --> Pages;
Content --> Blocks;
Content --> Widgets;
Content --> Templates;

Comment: This is now resolved! You can indeed find the block in: Content --> Blocks; It's called: "Porto - Custom Notice Block" Thanks for your help Marcony :o)

Comment: Greeeeeeat! I am glad to help you thinking on finding the solution. That's why 2 heads think better than just one. Proud of you!